# App crashes when build release with React Native 0.60: Unhandled JS Exception: null is not an object (evaluating 'n.apply')

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm building an app with React Native 0.60.0. I tried to build to my real device and my app was crashed right at the launching.

[image: Here the log I got]

I did not implement any code with API so I think it came from some 3rd libraries or RN 0.60.0

Answer (score 0):

Oop! I found the reason of my issue. It came from Reactotron library. I will close this topic from now.